# "a Euler graph" or "an Euler graph"?

Tags: graph-theory, article-writing

I recently referenced the following article in my manuscript.

> S. Toida, Properties of a Euler graph, J. Franklin Inst. 295 (1973) 343–34.

However, my grammar checker flagged “a Euler graph” as a grammatical error, stating that it should be "an Euler graph." I am confused as to whether both forms are acceptable and whether it is appropriate to respect the original intention when encountering potential errors in titles when citing.

**Edit:** I noticed some conflicting opinions in  comments. I'm uncertain about which suggestion is the best. John Bentin
's answer seems to be the most convincing.

Comment: If that's what the title really was, then don't change it when you're citing it. If you want to point out the error, you could maybe write “Properties of a [*sic*] Euler graph”.

Comment: When you say this was flagged by your "editor," are you referring to the editor of the journal you applied to (a person)?  Or are you referring to the software you're using to write the article?  I would be surprised if a professional journal editor (a person) asked you to deliberately mis-report the official title of a published article.

Comment: @SyntaxJunkie: It would be reasonable for a professional journal editor to point out what might be an error in the transcription of the title.

Comment: @psmears.  I agree with you completely.  Although that doesn't seem to be the case here since there was no "may be" in the original post: *my editor flagged “a Euler graph” as a grammatical error, stating that it should be "an Euler graph.*  But that is why I asked the question.  That seems like the kind of absolute comment that a grammar checker might make.  A human, especially one experienced enough to be an editor, would probably have known the error could be in the original article, and asked the author to *check for* a transcription error in the references.

Comment: @SyntaxJunkie: You may well be right, but I can also imagine an editor who would find it difficult to believe that a fellow editor would allow such an error in the title of a published paper :)

Comment: Related, noting the historical change of the pronunciation: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/315906/pronunciation-of-the-name-leonhard-euler

Comment: @SyntaxJunkie Sorry. I just noticed this ambiguity. In fact, it was my text editor that detected this issue, not a professional editor (a person). The manuscript has not been submitted to any journal yet. I will honestly respond if any edits are pointed out after the submission. Thanks every body. Thank you for your detailed response (along with others).

Comment: I'd leave any mistake in the title of a reference alone, and if this mistake (to the extent that it is generally considered a mistake) bugs me enough, I'd indirectly assert my position by making sure to include the phrase "an Euler graph" somewhere (perhaps multiple times) in the body of my own text.

Comment: This isn't a math question, it's a question about English grammar

Comment: @ David Lui In principle, yes, but its background is  the mathematician, Euler. If I were to inquire on English grammar stack, they would recommend visiting this website.

Comment: What I normally do is cite the title exactly as it is even if it is grammatically incorrect, but then use correct grammar if I refer to the concept myself in the paper, so cite the article as ''a Euler graph'' but write ''an Euler graph'' if you refer to it elsewhere.

Comment: Not saying this is the case here but sometimes titles contain grammatical errors intentionally. It's a title, not a sentence. They can use whatever words they want.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

There are two questions here. The first is easily answered: Is “a Euler graph” correct? No. It should be “an Euler graph”.

The other question is more tricky: If the source of a cited piece of text contains an error in the grammar or spelling, or some other obvious error, should I correct it? First, you should try to reference the original source; it may be that the error was introduced in the secondary source that you first used. If so, quote the original source. If the original source has the error, then it is arguably appropriate to quote it verbatim but with “[sic]” appended. That is what I would do. However, there are different ideas about this. One is that peppering quoted text with “[sic]” is a slippery slope; just copy it as it stands. The other is simply to correct obvious mistakes without comment. That makes reading easier but offends the principle of historical precision. In the end, the decision is yours or the editor's, depending on who holds sway here.

(Added in edit) In this case, the [original source](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/001600327390046X) (thanks to Gonçalo) is a reputable edited journal and bears the error. So some explanation is called for. My guess is that the author and/or editor thought that *Euler* was pronounced “yooler”, in analogy to *eulogy*, for which of course the form *a eulogy* is correct.

Comment: Re: "That makes reading easier but offends the principle of historical precision": In the specific case of a reference, it also makes it harder for readers to find the referenced work.

Comment: @ruakh : True. That's why I prefer the verbatim form—but with “[sic]” to stop the reader “autocorrecting”.

Comment: _If_ someone uses the pronunciation "yooler" in English, _then_ it is "a Euler graph". But _if_ you use a pronunciation "oiler" (which is closer to the native (German)), then it is "an Euler graph". The pronunciation of foreign proper names is not trivial. For example, is it "an Hermitian operator" because Hermite's name starts with a vowel sound in French? And if something is named for an Arab called ʿAlī, does that start with a consonant (glottal stop) or a vowel (A)? I believe there is no other rule in English than to write it according to the pronunciation the writer prefers.

Comment: I have not yet heard anyone pronounce Euler with any pronunciation apart from one like ''oiler''.

Comment: @Tom - evidently you are younger than some of us. When I first encountered the name as a teenager in the late 1970s, "Yooler" was the pronunciation I learned. However, in my undergraduate years in college, it was quickly corrected. And "Yooler" has not completely died out in English mathematics, for example, you will hear it in some Numberphile videos.

Comment: @PaulSinclair I was taught the correct way to say it but I was reading about Euler long before speaking or hearing about Euler so I still think of it as Yooler from time to time.

Comment: @Fattie : You can listen to the pronunciation [here](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/ef/De-Leonhard_Euler.ogg). Wikipedia does not offer an alternative to /ˈɔɪlər/ (or  OY-lər in English pronunciation respelling). What is your source for “You-ler”?

Comment: So there is a lot of evidence, also reading the comment by Paul Sinclair, that graph theorist Toida (later known for [Toida's conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toida%27s_conjecture)) used a pronunciation in English, in 1973, by which the paper title _Properties of a Euler graph_ was correct. And the journal did not require any change to that. So there is a task for historians to search through English-language literature and see how the frequencies of "a Euler" and "an Euler" (and also Eulerian etc.) have changed over time.

Comment: [Encyclopædia Britannica article Euler characteristic](https://www.britannica.com/science/Euler-characteristic) uses "a Euler characteristic" twice (see end of third paragraph). Amusingly, if you click "Listen to article" in the top of that page, the robot (speech synthesis software) that reads aloud says _a oiler_, which is of course silly.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen You can see the trends yourself using the [Google Ngram Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=an+Euler%2Ca+Euler&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3). “an Euler” has been much more common for the last century.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen While the pronunciation "yooler" may be encountered, it's still wrong. We should not be normalising incorrectness, despite the current political post-truth landscape in which being wrong is lauded as commendable.

Comment: @PrimeMover, I want to be sure you use _an Euclidean space_ (not _a Euclidean space_) since certainly you stick to a (classical?) Greek pronunciation of the name Εὐκλείδης?

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen yes of course I do. Doesn't everyone?

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen Normalising incorrect usage is pandering to the arrogantly ignorant.

Comment: @PrimeMover You can start a separate thread here, _"an Euclidean space" or "a Euclidean space"?_ I am quite certain a majority will consider your usage incorrect.

Answer (score 19):

*An* is used before words that start with a vowel sound, and Euler is pronounced /ˈɔɪlər/, so there is no choice to be made.

When referencing something, though, you have to use the exact title.

Comment: Almost all English words starting *eu-*, apart from names, would take *a* rather than *an*, so this may be a spell-check pattern recognition issue.  Examples include: eucharistic, eugenics, eulogy, euphemism, euphony, european and euthanasia.

Comment: @Henry but OP's grammar checker is suggesting "an" rather than "a", so it is either more sophisticated or less sophisticated than you suggest. (Indeed, Word prefers "a eulogy" but "an Euler graph", so is more sophisticated.)

Comment: "_An_ is used", "there is no choice to be made", "use the exact title".  Those three statements do not go together.

Comment: @Teepeemm In context, they absolutely do. "An" is the correct choice among "a" and "an"; there is no choice among the correct options (since there is only one), and while the paper title contains a mistake, any citation must include that same mistake.

Comment: @preferred_anon But this means that there is a choice: do you use the "correct choice", or do you include the citation's mistake.  There's arguments for either (hence this question and its five answers and 6 votes among three options).  I agree with including the mistake, but saying there is a "correct choice" that should not be taken requires more than a sentence of explanation.

Answer (score 12):

I'd use "an Euler graph". This is because the pronunciation of "Euler" begins with a vowel sound ("oi"), so "an" is preferred. Besides, [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eulerian_path) and most other articles uses "an" too, so using "an" will be better for consistency. However, I don't think it really matters, as long as your readers can understand.

Comment: Note: "Euler" is sometimes pronounced as "Yooler" in English, which would lead to dropping the n. 
However, as this a reference, the title should be reproduced as it was in the original.

Comment: @Chieron Agreed: as a Brit I've never heard the pronunciation as "Oiler", always "Yewler", so "an" would feel weird and wrong to me here. Is "Oiler" a US-Eng thing, or just a more-correct thing?

Comment: @DewiMorgan "Oiler" is (close to) the original German pronunciation of the name, so that would make it the "more-correct" option.

Comment: @Oliphaunt Thanks! :D I'll try to fix my eyes' reading of it then. (Though, "van Gogh" suggests that someone's own pronunciation of their own name isn't necessarily always considered "correct" in English)

Comment: @DewiMorgan Interesting - this does appear to be a US/UK difference. The German "oiler" pronunciation is absolutely the standard in the US, with "yewler" not even regarded as an acceptable alternative. I was surprised to learn that the latter was the default in the UK.

Comment: @MarkFoskey I'm American, and I don't agree that it's not regarded as an acceptable alternative. I learned and used the British pronunciation as a child because the spelling matched that of other words with the same pronunciation, such as "euglena", "Europe", and "eugenics." I didn't realize there was another pronunciation until I heard it in class. Keep in mind that the instant availability of pronunciation and spelling aids via the web did not exist back then.

Comment: Consistency has nothing to do with it. How many times have you heard someone call a request an ask or a revelation a reveal? Do you really want to sound like those people?

Comment: I'm British, and it didn't dawn on me that some people said "yooler"before coming across the original title here (which, incidentally, was published in a Canadian journal). I don't agree that  "yooler" is accepted standard British English.

Comment: I haven't heard anyone pronounce it like ''yooler''.

Comment: I am also surprised by the ability of my colleagues to totally mispronounce vowels in Spanish names even though there are only 5 of them and it's clear what they are.

Comment: @JohnBentin You should have seen my reaction when I was in graduate school and some engineering student pronounced Cauchy as "Cowchee".

Comment: I'm in the UK and only ever hear "Oiler".

Answer (score 8):

Based on the comments, I think there is a strong case to quote it exactly, with no "[sic]". There appears to be a UK/US difference here. Normally you would not convert "colour" to "color" when citing a title, for instance (or vice versa). So, in the same way, this should be retained as a normal national language variation.

Answer (score 2):

If you pronounce Euler as "You-ler", the answer is "A euler."

(Exactly as, for example, a yule log, or any other of the zillion Yi- words in English.)

If you pronounce Euler as "oo-ler", the answer is "An oo-ler."

The English language rule has nothing to do with starting with a vowel, it's about **starting with a vowel sound**.

Some points,

1. I have never ever ever heard You-ler prounced "oo-ler" "because of the German". Note for example that the word "volkswagen" is never, ever, ever pronounced "German -like" in English.
2. The a -> an transition in English has nothing to do with grammar, it's not a "grammar rule".  It's a phonology issue: sandhi.
3. As everyone has pointed out, you don't "fix" regional spellings (but that's probably not an issue here, as it is "a yooler" everywhere).

Comment: While I've heard YOO-ler since primary school in Chicagoland, I often hear OY-ler among university folks. OO-ler? I have never heard that. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leonhard_Euler +1 on the obvious rationale.

Comment: It is possible someone pronounces it "pumpernickel" but they would simply be wrong. "Euler" is [pronounced](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Euler) [ˈɔɪləɹ] (oiler).